# Get metadata for mobi/azw3

Tags: php, python, metadata

There is a [python script](https://github.com/pwr/KSP/blob/master/tools/DumpMobiHeader.py) to get metadata from a mobi/azw3 file, I try to get the **title/author** by `php` with the code:

```
$fp=fopen('test.mobi', 'r');
fseek($fp,1);
echo fgets($fp, 503);
```

where `503` is the position for **title** (see [this wiki](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/MOBI#MOBI_Header)) it seems not the title. I think I need to set the ending of the steam, but how?

Comment: Do you want to create a php script similar to python script?

Comment: no just give me an example to get the metadata, such as title correctly.

Comment: `File[503] != Header[503]` So if delete any `metadata` key your index returned wrong data ! Need reading `byte header` index not `File reading Index` !

Comment: maybe I need 'unpack' then?

Comment: Maybe you can solve this calling an external tool. See [these answers](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6517/command-line-extraction-of-metadata-title-author-from-epub-file/8746).

Comment: The offset to the title(full name) is not fixed. Parse the first record information to find the MOBI header, using the record data offset field. Then get the full name using the full name offset field. Also open with 'rb' mode, because it's in a binary format.